# data.table mapping

Tags: r, mapping, data.table

I need to do a bulk re-mapping on a large (many millions of rows) dataset.

Sample data:

```
DT = data.table(yr = sample(3)+2000, a1 = sample(12), a2 = sample(12))[order(yr)]
DT
      yr a1 a2
 1: 2001  2  8
 2: 2001  3 12
 3: 2001 10  4
 4: 2001  9  6
 5: 2002  7  7
 6: 2002 11  3
 7: 2002  5  2
 8: 2002  1 11
 9: 2003  8  5
10: 2003 12  1
11: 2003  6  9
12: 2003  4 10

DTmap = data.table(a1 = 1:12, b=10001:10012)
DTmap
    a1     b
 1:  1 10001
 2:  2 10002
 3:  3 10003
 4:  4 10004
 5:  5 10005
 6:  6 10006
 7:  7 10007
 8:  8 10008
 9:  9 10009
10: 10 10010
11: 11 10011
12: 12 10012
```

I'd like to map *both* columns a1 and a2 in DT with the mapping in DTmap. Ignore the fact that they are simply 10000 different - that is an artifact of the sample data to easily check accuracy of results. 
I can do this with a sequence of joins like this:

```
setkey(DT,a1)
setkey(DTmap,a1)
DT.merge1 <- DT[DTmap]

setkey(DT.merge1,a2)
setnames(DTmap,c("a2","b"))
setkey(DTmap,a2)

DT.merge2 <- DT.merge1[DTmap]
DT.merge2
      yr a1 a2     b   i.b
 1: 2003 12  1 10012 10001
 2: 2002  5  2 10005 10002
 3: 2002 11  3 10011 10003
 4: 2001 10  4 10010 10004
 5: 2003  8  5 10008 10005
 6: 2001  9  6 10009 10006
 7: 2002  7  7 10007 10007
 8: 2001  2  8 10002 10008
 9: 2003  6  9 10006 10009
10: 2003  4 10 10004 10010
11: 2002  1 11 10001 10011
12: 2001  3 12 10003 10012

DT.merge2[, `:=` (a1 = NULL, a2 = NULL)]
setnames(DT.merge2,c("year","b1","b2"))
DT.merge2
    year    b1    b2
 1: 2003 10012 10001
 2: 2002 10005 10002
 3: 2002 10011 10003
 4: 2001 10010 10004
 5: 2003 10008 10005
 6: 2001 10009 10006
 7: 2002 10007 10007
 8: 2001 10002 10008
 9: 2003 10006 10009
10: 2003 10004 10010
11: 2002 10001 10011
12: 2001 10003 10012
```

It seems like there would be a way to do this within the data.table syntax using by() or something, but I can't figure it out. I'm a pretty new R coder, but have lots of experience with other languages. 
Is this possible? The above is relatively fast, but is lots of coding with several sorts (via setkey). It would seem that using by() with an index then updating these values via reference would be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match` for that:

```
DT[, `:=` (b1 = DTmap$b[match(a1,DTmap$a1)], b2 = DTmap$b[match(a2,DTmap$a1)])]
```

Or as @Frank suggested:

```
DT[DTmap, on = .(a1), b1 := i.b][DTmap, on = .(a2=a1), b2 := i.b]
```

with both approaches you get:

```
> DT
      yr a1 a2    b1    b2
 1: 2001  7  8 10007 10008
 2: 2001  4 11 10004 10011
 3: 2001  6 12 10006 10012
 4: 2001  8  2 10008 10002
 5: 2002 11  9 10011 10009
 6: 2002  9  5 10009 10005
 7: 2002 10  4 10010 10004
 8: 2002  2 10 10002 10010
 9: 2003 12  7 10012 10007
10: 2003  3  1 10003 10001
11: 2003  5  3 10005 10003
12: 2003  1  6 10001 10006
```

Especially when joining on multiple columns, the 2nd approach is much easier.

---

To remove the `a1` and `a2` columns, just add `[, c('a1','a2') := NULL]`, e.g.:

```
DT[, `:=` (b1 = DTmap$b[match(a1,DTmap$a1)], b2 = DTmap$b[match(a2,DTmap$a1)])
   ][, c('a1','a2') := NULL]
```

you will then get:

```
> DT
      yr    b1    b2
 1: 2001 10007 10008
 2: 2001 10004 10011
 3: 2001 10006 10012
 4: 2001 10008 10002
 5: 2002 10011 10009
 6: 2002 10009 10005
 7: 2002 10010 10004
 8: 2002 10002 10010
 9: 2003 10012 10007
10: 2003 10003 10001
11: 2003 10005 10003
12: 2003 10001 10006
```

---

On a side note: When providing sample data with random value generators (like `sample` or `rnorm`) it is better to use `set.seed()`.

**Used data:**

```
set.seed(2004)
DT = data.table(yr = sample(3)+2000, a1 = sample(12), a2 = sample(12))[order(yr)]
DTmap = data.table(a1 = 1:12, b=10001:10012)
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Got it. I'll use set.seed() next time. On the first join in @Frank's solution, why do you use i.b? It works with just b there. The second time, I understand because otherwise it would be a duplicate column.

Comment: @JesseBlocher the `i.` prefix refers to columns in `i`; basically `i` is where you specify which rows to select with an index-vector or a reference data.table ([see here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for more info what `i` means)